# Reusable UITableHeaderFooterView Loose ImageView Orientation State

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an expandable `UITableView` with specific cell, header and footer heights. When user taps a header, cells are started to shown below it (section expand). When user taps again, section collapse.

**My problem** is that when user taps the header, title becomes green and arrows (`UIImageView`) orient change. When I don't use `dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView`, everything works perfect but when I reuse the header, green title and arrow orientation doesn't look as expected on tap or scroll.

In below picture, New York's title color looks ok but arrow orientation is wrong. Also Manhattan, header is expanded but doesn't get green color and right `UIImageView` orientation.

**P.S:** I know this has been asked lots of times but I can't figure out which one is the proper way.

Header View Class:

```
protocol ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate {
func toggleSection(header: DistrictTableViewHeader, section: Int)
}

class DistrictTableViewHeader: UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
var delegate: ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate?
var section: Int!

let nameLabel: UILabel = {
   let l = UILabel()
    l.textColor = Color.DistrictsPage.headerTextColor
    return l
}()

private let arrowImage: UIImageView = {
  let i = UIImageView()
    let image = UIImage(named: "ileri")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
    i.image = image
    i.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return i
}()
var isColapsed: Bool!{
    didSet{
        layoutSubviews()
    }
}

override init(reuseIdentifier: String?) {

    super.init(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectHeaderAction)))
    nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    nameLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
    nameLabel.textColor = Color.DistrictsPage.headerTextColor
    contentView.addSubview(nameLabel)
    nameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    nameLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true

    arrowImage.tintColor =  UIColor(red:0.32, green:0.36, blue:0.36, alpha:1.0)
    arrowImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.addSubview(arrowImage)
    arrowImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    arrowImage.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    arrowImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

@objc func selectHeaderAction(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let cell = gestureRecognizer.view as! DistrictTableViewHeader
    self.isColapsed = !isColapsed
    if(!isColapsed){
        let degrees : Double = 90 //the value in degrees
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { [weak self] in
            self?.nameLabel.textColor = Color.Common.garantiLightGreen
            self?.arrowImage.tintColor = Color.Common.garantiLightGreen
            self?.arrowImage.rotate(CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))
            self?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.97, blue:0.97, alpha:1.0)
        }
    }else{
        let degrees : Double = 0 //the value in degrees
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { [weak self] in
            self?.nameLabel.textColor = Color.DistrictsPage.headerTextColor
            self?.arrowImage.tintColor = UIColor.black
            self?.arrowImage.rotate(CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))
            self?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        }
    }
    delegate?.toggleSection(header: self, section: cell.section)
}

func customInit(title: String, section: Int, delegate: ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate) {
    self.nameLabel.text = title
    self.nameLabel.accessibilityIdentifier = title
    self.section = section
    self.delegate = delegate
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

}

}
```

How I initialize the header:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 60
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header: DistrictTableViewHeader = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterView(withIdentifier: headerId) as! DistrictTableViewHeader
    //let header = DistrictTableViewHeader()

    header.isColapsed = !self.cities[section].isExpanded
    header.customInit(title: self.cities[section].name, section: section, delegate: self)
    return header
}
```

How I expand/collapse:

```
func toggleSection(header: DistrictTableViewHeader, section: Int) {
    self.cities[section].isExpanded = !self.cities[section].isExpanded
    let contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset
    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

**EDIT:** For the UITableView gurus, I added also a sample project :)
Sample Project Link:

https://github.com/emreond/tableViewLayoutIssue

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you dequeue a reusable view you must reset all changes that could have happened to it.

In this case you are setting `header.isColapsed` but that does not reset all the view's state that it needs to.  The view state changing code in `selectHeaderAction` needs to also be called when the view is reused.

It will take a little refactoring to do right.  Change the `isColapse` setter to do more:

```
var isColapsed: Bool!{
  didSet{
     if(!isColapsed){
        let degrees : Double = 90 //the value in degrees
        self?.nameLabel.textColor = Color.Common.garantiLightGreen
        self?.arrowImage.tintColor = Color.Common.garantiLightGreen
        self?.arrowImage.rotate(CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))
        self?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.97, green:0.97, blue:0.97, alpha:1.0)
     }else{
        let degrees : Double = 0 //the value in degrees
        self?.nameLabel.textColor = Color.DistrictsPage.headerTextColor
        self?.arrowImage.tintColor = UIColor.black
        self?.arrowImage.rotate(CGFloat(degrees * .pi/180))
        self?.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
      }
      layoutSubviews()
  }
}
```

And make the tapper gesture do less:

```
@objc func selectHeaderAction(gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let cell = gestureRecognizer.view as! DistrictTableViewHeader
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { [weak self] in
        self.isColapsed = !isColapsed
    }
    delegate?.toggleSection(header: self, section: cell.section)
}
```

I think that should fix it. Tell me if it works.

---

You are doing rotation wrong.  Adding a CAAnimation is cool, but you can't easily cancel it when the view is reused.  Instead just change the `transform` property and let the UIView.animate block deal with the animation at a higher level.

```
func rotate(_ toValue: CGFloat) {
  self.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: toValue)
}
```

---

Next you are reloading the table which is canceling all the animation that you want to do.

```
 func toggleSection(header: DistrictTableViewHeader, section: Int) {
    self.cities[section].isExpanded = !self.cities[section].isExpanded
  let count = self.cities[section].districts.count
  let indexPaths:[IndexPath] = (0..<count).map{ IndexPath.init(row: $0, section: section) }
  if self.cities[section].isExpanded {
    self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic);
  }else{
    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic);
  }
}
```

Comment: When I tap the header, SOMETIMES, It rotates the arrow but usually It doesn't rotate the arrow.

Comment: Is the gesture being triggered.  apple recommend that you don't attach gesture to individual views - https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/IncorporatingGestureSupport/IncorporatingGestureSupport.html

Comment: Are u asking If selectHeaderAction triggered? Yes, It is triggered.

Comment: I added a sample project.

Comment: Actually, I was tried insert, delete row instead of reload data but It causes some bugs. Now, I have duplicate headers when I scroll and also I need to scroll to expanded heather but with insert, delete row It has some UI bug (content inset problem). Can you please share me a example project If It worked for you? Let me check it. Thank you for your effort.